# D3.js conflict with Boostrap

Tags: html, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, c3.js

[image: d3js error]

I am getting the above errors while trying to add a c3js/d3js graph. I am using d3 v5 for this project.
I also have bootstrap 3 linked to the html.

```
<head>
<title>Default</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.5/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="file:///../Test/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.5/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Strangely enough, if I remove the bootstrap.min.css line, the graph works, but obviously bootstrap doesn't work. Hence the conflict.

What can I do to make them work together? I know there are projects where they both work together, I just can't figure out how.

The following snippet demonstrates the issue:

```js
var jsonObj = [{"ChildId":0,"Year":2019,"Quarter":1,"QuarterShort":"2019 Q1","Revenue":16.57,"Cost":8.69,"PnlPct":52.46,"Em":7.88,"EmPct":47.54,"Cost":7.2,"CostPct":43.45,"Technical":0.05,"TechnicalPct":0.31,"MiscCost":1.44,"MiscCostPct":8.69,"ParentId":0,"RandomId":0,"StartDate":"2019-06-24T00:00:00","WeekId":137,"IsPrev":1},{"ChildId":0,"Year":2019,"Quarter":2,"QuarterShort":"2019 Q2","Revenue":16.8,"Cost":9.39,"PnlPct":55.88,"Em":7.41,"EmPct":44.12,"Cost":7.84,"CostPct":46.67,"Technical":0.12,"TechnicalPct":0.71,"MiscCost":1.43,"MiscCostPct":8.49,"ParentId":0,"RandomId":0,"StartDate":"2019-07-01T00:00:00","WeekId":138,"IsPrev":0}]
$.each(jsonObj, function (key, fp) {
    var curr = fp.StartDate.substr(0, 10);
    fp.StartDate = curr;
    jsonObj[key] = fp;
});
var finChart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#finpctgraphs',
    padding: {
        left: 50,
        right: 50
    },
    data: {
        json: jsonObj,
        keys: {
            x: 'StartDate',
            value: ['PnlPct', 'CostPct', 'TechnicalPct', 'MiscCostPct']
        },
        labels: true
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            //type: 'category'
            type: 'timeseries',
            // if true, treat x value as localtime (Default)
            // if false, convert to UTC internally
            localtime: false,
            tick: {
                format: '%d/%m',
                culling: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.5/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="file:///../Test/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.5/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-top: 1px solid #000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-left: 1px solid #000000;margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;display:block;text-align:left;width: 1000px;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;border-radius:5px;' class='' id='finpctgraphs'></div>
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yemtpr4q/1/) without bootstrap.css
Not working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf7jm4rt/) with boostrap.css

Comment: It would be easier for other people to debug this problem if you provided a code example that used HTTPS URLs from a CDN instead of file scheme URLs.

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 2.x is beyond end of life and doesn't get security updates. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @Quentin I've made the CDN edit. Also, changing the jquery version to 3.4.1 didn't do anything for the problem

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://i.imgur.com/LadFaIS.png

Comment: "Also, changing the jquery version to 3.4.1 didn't do anything for the problem " — I said it was a security risk, not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Quentin I've edited the question to add the demo jsFiddle

Comment: @altocumulus  I've edited the question to add the demo jsFiddle

Comment: — You need to provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed.

Comment: @Quentin I've added the code. I hope this meets your requirement to look into this issue and provide a resolution. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap CSS seems to conflict with the way C3.js calculates the dimensions of the container into which the chart is rendered. This can be solved by overriding the implicit height as determined by C3 with the configuration parameter [`size.height`](https://c3js.org/reference.html#size-height).

```
size: {
  height: 320
}
```

Have a look at the updated working demo:

```js
var jsonObj = [{"ChildId":0,"Year":2019,"Quarter":1,"QuarterShort":"2019 Q1","Revenue":16.57,"Cost":8.69,"PnlPct":52.46,"Em":7.88,"EmPct":47.54,"Cost":7.2,"CostPct":43.45,"Technical":0.05,"TechnicalPct":0.31,"MiscCost":1.44,"MiscCostPct":8.69,"ParentId":0,"RandomId":0,"StartDate":"2019-06-24T00:00:00","WeekId":137,"IsPrev":1},{"ChildId":0,"Year":2019,"Quarter":2,"QuarterShort":"2019 Q2","Revenue":16.8,"Cost":9.39,"PnlPct":55.88,"Em":7.41,"EmPct":44.12,"Cost":7.84,"CostPct":46.67,"Technical":0.12,"TechnicalPct":0.71,"MiscCost":1.43,"MiscCostPct":8.49,"ParentId":0,"RandomId":0,"StartDate":"2019-07-01T00:00:00","WeekId":138,"IsPrev":0}]
$.each(jsonObj, function (key, fp) {
    var curr = fp.StartDate.substr(0, 10);
    fp.StartDate = curr;
    jsonObj[key] = fp;
});
var finChart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#finpctgraphs',
    size: {
      height: 480
    },
    padding: {
        left: 50,
        right: 50
    },
    data: {
        json: jsonObj,
        keys: {
            x: 'StartDate',
            value: ['PnlPct', 'CostPct', 'TechnicalPct', 'MiscCostPct']
        },
        labels: true
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            //type: 'category'
            type: 'timeseries',
            // if true, treat x value as localtime (Default)
            // if false, convert to UTC internally
            localtime: false,
            tick: {
                format: '%d/%m',
                culling: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.5/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="file:///../Test/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.5/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-top: 1px solid #000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000;border-left: 1px solid #000000;margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;display:block;text-align:left;width: 1000px;font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;border-radius:5px;' class='' id='finpctgraphs'></div>
```